# Does Google Analytics run in a separate thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics SDK in a iOS project, and I'm a little concerned about performance issues about it. I'm not sure if tracker invocations run in a separated thread for avoiding blocking the main thread.

Someone knows if it runs in a separated thread?, is there any way to figure it out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the SDK work with a queue of events, every X events or seconds the async thread communicate with the Google servers and send all the queue events. Use the Debug mode to view the logs.

```
  // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
  [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
  // Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
  [GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
```